# Trying to deploy laravel project to VPS

Tags: php, laravel

Hello this is my first time trying deploy laravel project to vps over ubuntu.
I have installed all requirements - php 8, composer 2+, mysql etc. but now when I try to create new dummy project to test it out i get this issue all the time for almost all packages

[image]

Comment: This question is not clear, what is the issue here?

Comment: Why it says "failed to download..." for all packages? Not a single package is installed correctly... is that okay or?

Comment: You really shouldn't run anything as root unless you absolutely have to. you can use docker images

Comment: @SeadSilajdzic and also, if you are going to share an error, share it as text because if the image goes down, this post has no meaning and would be totally not understandable... You can also try deleting `~/.composer/cache` or `~/.config/composer/cache`.

Comment: @Sead also please paste the actual text output into your post, rather than just a screenshot.  It makes things a lot easier for everyone else.